# An expression tree may not contain an out argument variable declaration AutoMapper map from

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I have the following mapping (AutoMapper Version="10.1.1"):

```
CreateMap<FooClass, BarClass>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.Status, 
        opt => opt.MapFrom(
            src => Enum.TryParse(src.Status ?? string.Empty, out Status result) ? result : Status.TEST_READY)
    );
```

But got an error:

> CS8198: An expression tree may not contain an out argument variable
> declaration

Any idea how to accomplish this without needing to create a custom resolver?

Thanks

Comment: You just need to write a method to use instead of `Enum.TryParse` which doesn't have an out parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try add *src* and destination *(dest)* in lambda.

```
CreateMap<FooClass, BarClass>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.Status, 
        opt => opt.MapFrom(
            (src, dest) => Enum.TryParse(src.Status ?? string.Empty, out Status result) ? result : Status.TEST_READY)
    );
```